# Mocking injected fields with @javax.inject.Inject with Mockito and Wicket causes Wicket to treat to field as child component

Tags: mockito, wicket, cdi

I have a WicketPage with an injected field with CDI as follows:

```
public class Page extends BaseWebPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private Facade facade;

public Page () {
    super("Title");
}
}
```

I have a unittest in which I mock said field:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PageTest{

    @Mock
    private Facade facadeMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private Page cut;

    WicketTester tester = new WicketTester(new MockApplication());

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Entity entity = newEntity("1", "John"));
        Mockito.when(facadeMock.find()).thenReturn(entity );
    }

    @Test
    public void testOverzicht() {
        tester.startPage(cut);
//below line throws stackTrace
        tester.assertRenderedPage(Page.class);
    }
}
```

Strangely, Wicket can't make sense of my injected Mock. At a certain point Wicket starts to proces it's components of which the facadeMock is suddenly one. It then fails an instanceof Component check which fails becauses it
's an Mockito'd proxy which causes Wicket to throw the IllegalArgumentException. It then continues to parse and then cast the facadeMock to an Object[] in it's detach method. Stacktrace added below for clarification which causes a classCastException.

NOTE: Names of classes and packages are altered for privacy reasons.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type of object facadeMock
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.getId(MarkupContainer.java:1068)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children_indexOf(MarkupContainer.java:1130)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.put(MarkupContainer.java:1318)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.add(MarkupContainer.java:175)
    at nl.app.Page.onInitialize(Page.java:53)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.fireInitialize(Component.java:877)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.internalInitialize(MarkupContainer.java:961)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.isPageStateless(Page.java:463)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:244)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester$LastPageRecordingPageRendererProvider$1.respond(BaseWicketTester.java:2755)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:890)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:712)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:651)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.startPage(BaseWicketTester.java:876)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.startPage(BaseWicketTester.java:893)
    at nl.app.Page.testOverzicht(PageTest.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
ERROR [RequestHandlerStack.detach()] Error detaching RequestHandler
java.lang.ClassCastException: nl.app.common.facade.Facade$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$7b6f60ae incompatible w
ith [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at java.lang.ClassCastException.<init>(ClassCastException.java:58)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.children_size(MarkupContainer.java:1305)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.detachChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1603)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.detach(Component.java:1186)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.detach(PageProvider.java:327)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.detach(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.detach(RequestCycle.java:901)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.detach(RequestHandlerStack.java:180)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.onDetach(RequestCycle.java:636)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.detach(RequestCycle.java:589)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:712)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.processRequest(BaseWicketTester.java:651)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.startPage(BaseWicketTester.java:876)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.startPage(BaseWicketTester.java:893)
    at nl.app.Page.testOverzicht(PageTest.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Interesting how facadeMock sneaks into the children of your page. Could you place breakpoints into MarkupContainer$ChildList to see when it gets added?

Comment: It's not in an instance of ChildList, the children field is the facadeMock. I added breakpoint pretty much everywhere but I have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: Please create a quickstart so we can debug the problem.

Comment: ```at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.add(MarkupContainer.java:175)
    at nl.app.Page.onInitialize(Page.java:53)
```
This looks strange. What are you doing in Page#onInitialize(), line 53 ?

Comment: adding a new ListView

Sven: ill see about the quickstart

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest a slightly different approach which will not make use of `@InjectMocks`.

From CDI perspective, the way to achieve a behavior where one bean uses a different implementation in tests (mocked) and in real scenario (fully implemented) is to use **`@Alternative`**. It allows to do the same as mocking but....well without mocking anything. The [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#alternatives) itself speaks of alternatives in the context of mocking.

The way it works is as follows. First you have your bean with its real implementation:

```
public MyBean {
  public void awesomeMethod() {
    doStuff(); //do what you really want and or need here
  }
}
```

Now there is this other `@Alternative` bean which extends your bean:

```
@Alternative
public MyMockedBean extends MyBean {
  public void awesomeMethod() {
    // do some other, (mocked) stuff here, or don't do anything at all
  }
}
```

Now, last but not least, **`@Alternative` is by default disabled**. That means CDI will normally ignore it and use the original bean instead. In order to enable it, you can use two approaches:

- `@Priority`, which enables it all the time and globally. You do not want this in your case.
- `beans.xml`, or more presicely, listing the alternative in `beans.xml`. This way you enable the alternative on a per bean archive basis.**This is the way to go** - simply add a different `beans.xml` to your tests and list the `@Alternative` there. That way you will retain standard behvaiour out of the tests scope, and use 'mocked' beans in your tests.

`beans.xml` should contain following lines in order to enable the `@Alternative`:

```
<alternatives>
  <class>com.whatever.MyMockedBean</class>
</alternatives>
```